# How to disable YouCompleteMe's error checking?

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, filetype-c++

I have recently installed **YouCompleteMe** and can't figure out how to disable its error checking feature. I am developing in C++ and wanted to use **Neomake** as my checker.

Comment: Read the documentation.

Comment: @romainl RTFM is against the concept and ethos of stack exchange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`g:ycm_show_diagnostics_ui`](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#the-gycm_show_diagnostics_ui-option) variable controls this:

```
The *g:ycm_show_diagnostics_ui* option

When set, this option turns on YCM's diagnostic display features. See the
_Diagnostic display_ section in the _User Manual_ for more details.
```

So, do:

```
let g:ycm_show_diagnostics_ui = 0
```